How do I navigate/change the location of my automated tasks in Task Scheduler?
I'm currently using RStudio for automating these tasks. I can't seem to change the location in the Task Scheduler app as the default location is "" and I can't edit or change it.
Tried checking under C:\Windows\System32\Tasks but I can't even open the Tasks folder and when I hover over it, it shows that the folder is empty.

Tasks are saved in filesystem AND registry. Here are some locations you can check.
File system:
C:\Windows\Tasks\   [files have .job extension]
C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\  [XML w/ no file extension]
Registry:
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache\Tasks
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache\Tree
Sometimes a task may get corrupted, you could try deleting and recreating it.
